When using a custom Playwright-Python browser context, how to take fail case screenshots using Pytest?
Recently introduced to test automation I have been using Playwright-Python to create tests for our small team's SaaS portal. Code below has been simplified and rewritten using saucedemo. Our use case would prefer this class structure of playwright functions however pytest CLI arguments are not compatible. Which means the functionality needs to be added as a fixture.
I have checked these stack overflow questions written using Selenium:
screenshot-on-test-case-failure-with-pytest and
save-screenshots-including-test-results
I believe the way the tests are initialized (sync_playwright,browser,context and page) needs to be changed because the Page is defined in the class _init_ to be able to locate the page
in conftest.py to take the screenshots after failure but I have not quite figured it out.
The main goal of this question is to successfully get fail case screenshots.
My code examples are below:
#sauceAutomation.py
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, Page, expect, sync_playwright
import time

class SaucyAutomation:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.playwright = sync_playwright().start()
        self.browser = self.playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False,args=["--start-maximized"])
        self.context = self.browser.new_context(no_viewport=False)
        self.page = self.context.new_page()
        self.environment = None
    
    def login(self, username, password):
        self.page.goto("https://www.saucedemo.com/")
        self.page.locator("//input[@id='user-name']").fill(username)
        self.page.locator("//input[@id='password']").fill(password)
        self.page.locator("//input[@id='login-button']").click()
    
    def burgerNavigate(self,menuItem):
        self.page.locator("//button[@id='react-burger-menu-btn']").click()
        self.page.locator("//a[@id='" + menuItem + "']").click()
    
    def logout(self):
        self.burgerNavigate("logout_sidebar_link")

## Done this way I could login and run multiple tests in the same page
# sauceDemo = SaucyAutomation()
# sauceDemo.login("standard_user", "secret_sauce")

def test_LoginLogout(): 
    sauceDemo = SaucyAutomation()
    sauceDemo.login("standard_user", "secret_sauce")
    time.sleep(2)
    sauceDemo.logout()

Which I use >pytest sauceAutomation.py
And here are my attempts at conftest.py:
#conftest.py
import os.path
import pytest_html
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, Page, expect, sync_playwright

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def context(request):
    playwright = sync_playwright().start()
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False,args=["--start-maximized"])
    context = browser.new_context(no_viewport=False)
    page = context.new_page()
    yield page

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True,wrapper=True )
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")

    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    rep = yield # TestReport Object
    screen_file = ''

    extras = getattr(rep, "extras", [])

    # we only look at actual failing test calls, not setup/teardown
    if rep.when == "call" and rep.failed:
        mode = "a" if os.path.exists("screenshots") else "w"
        with open("screenshots", mode, encoding="utf-8") as f:
            # let's also access a fixture for the fun of it
            if "tmp_path" in item.fixturenames:
                extra = " ({})".format(item.funcargs["tmp_path"])
            else:
                extra = ""
            #page = item.funcargs["page"]
            ##screenshot_dir = "/screenshots/"
            ##screenshot_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
            #screen_file = item.nodeid + ".png"
            #page.screenshot(path=screen_file)

            #print("MyDriver = " + str(mydriver))

            f.write(rep.nodeid + extra + "\n")
            #extras.append(pytest_html.extras.image(screen_file))
    return rep

def context() is currently not functional though I believe it is the correct way forward, and in pytest_runtest_makereport "page" is undefined (which is because page is not in any of the function args of my functions). Because none of my test cases include Page in their arguments what is the correct way to  access the page context in conftest.py besides defining it in the class __init__ or accessing it through item.funcargs?

There are some design related issues in your example.

Avoid writing page object models and tests in same file.
Page object models should not "OWN" selenium objects or playwright objects.
I see that you are using Playwright. There is a plugin called pytest-playwright to do what SaucyAutomation.__init__() or def context() is doing. So you don't have to implement it yourself. Additionally, pytest-playwright plugin implements it as a fixture so playwright's page object is available outside of SaucyAutomation class.

So SaucyAutomation.py looks like:
# SaucyAutomation.py

# Since its POM ideal named could be 'LoginPage'
class SaucyAutomation:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page

    ...


Create another file called test_login_logout.py:
# test_login_logout.py

# pytest-playwright plugin defines 'def page():' as a fixture
def test_LoginLogout(page):  
    sauceDemo = SaucyAutomation(page)
    sauceDemo.login("standard_user", "secret_sauce")
    time.sleep(2)
    sauceDemo.logout()

Since we are using pytest-playwright, Screenshots on failure are handled by pytest-playwright itself. Hence, we do not need to write def pytest_runtest_makereport() ourself.
So now run your tests like:
pytest -k test_LoginLogout --browser chromium --headed --screenshot only-on-failure --full-page-screenshot on
